# Why is my Gradle installation not working?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've downloaded Gradle and copied bin/gradle to my /usr/bin folder. I've also added GRADLE_HOME=/user/bin to my ~/.bash_profile. If I run

```
$ gradle -v
```

I get this error:

```
$ gradle -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /usr/bin/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .usr.bin.java
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

My java is here:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Finally, this is my .bash_profile:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/bin
export GRADLE_OPTS=/usr/bin/java
export PATH=${GRADLE_OPTS}:${GRADLE_HOME}:${PATH}
```

- I've removed other variable for PHP environment.

What's wrong? I've followed all http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/installation.html steps.

**SOLVED**

- I've copied entire /gradle-1.8 folder in /usr/bin/gradle-folder.
- Then I've created a symbolic link /usr/bin/gradle to /usr/bin/gradle-folder/bin/gradle

Now

```
$ gradle -v
```

returns ...

$ gradle -v

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-09-24 07:32:33 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     7970ec3503b4f5767ee1c1c69f8b4186c4763e3d

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.6.0_65 (Apple Inc. 20.65-b04-462)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9 x86_64
```

Comment: Try removing `GRADLE_OPTS`. Why not copy the complete gradle to say `/opts` and then add a symlink to gradle in `/usr/bin`? I think you are copying only gradle file to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I've downloaded gradle zip that contains bin folder. Yes: I've just copied only /bin/gradle file. In ZIP archive I've also /src folder. I've to move all gradle folder (with bin and src ...) in my /usr/bin folder?

Comment: why not using gradle wrapper (gradlew), with wrapper gradle configure gradle for you.

Comment: Mmmm I dont know what I've to do for use gradlew :-/

Comment: Solved: I've copied entire gradle-1.8 folder on my /usr/bin/gradle-fodler and I've create /usr/bin/gradle symbolic link to /usr/bin/gradle-folder/bin/gradle with chmod a+x. Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'll write an answer for this (including my comment above). One way is to have the gradle copied to some folder in `/usr/local` or to `/opts` and add a symlink to `gradle` and place it in `/usr/bin`. This is the manual way of doing things.
A more easier way is to install the [GVM (Groovy Environment Manager)](http://gvmtool.net/) script and let the script take care of installation and removal. You can easily have multiple version of Groovy, Grails, Gradle, Griffon without having to setup symlinks and stuff. The only thing is that it saves everything in your home directory.

Install the script.

```
curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
```

To install gradle give the command,

```
gvm install gradle
```

See the url linked above to read more above GVM.